# htaccess: Redirect old URL including URL-encoded characters like &20 to new URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-encoding

I need to redirect some specific URLs like

h_tp://www.domain.tld/folder/foo.-bar%20%3C/xyz%3E%3C/=

to another URL.

Sure I have to escape the dots and so on, but how do I have to handle escaped characters like spaces (%20) in my expresson to match this specific URL?

//edit:

This is what the redirect would look like:

```
RewriteRule ^/?fileadmin/Brosch%C3%BCren_Neu/Document\.pdf/?$ h_tp://www.domain.tld/newLocation.pdf [R=301,NC,L]
```

Sorry for the latency of my reaction, it was realy late yesterday.

Comment: Can you show your current rewrite rule?

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. This is a professional networking and configuration question and is better placed on other forums.

Comment: Are you sure this is not useful for people in this forum @Engineer Dollery? It was my first question at stackoverflow. I tried to complete my post with the solution so that it´s useful for others. It seems pretty hard to earn some reputation here..

Answer (score 1):

Adding the flag `[NE]` to the end of the rewrite rule should do it. `NE` stands for No Escape.
E.g.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^name/(.*)$ /username/$1 [R,NE]
```

will redirect `example.com/name/john smith` to `example.com/username/john smith`

Answer (score 0):

*I found the solution* right now! I was confused about the encoded links I should handle.

**I have to decode the encoded links first and write my rewrite rule using the decoded version. Now it looks like this (and it´s working):**

```
RewriteRule ^/?fileadmin/broschüren_neu/document\.pdf/?$ h_tp://www.domain.tld/newLocation.pdf [R=301,L]
```

I changed the http:// to h_tp:// to remove the links.